# Junit+Hibernate+Spring+H2 :inserts were executed without errors but select returns no data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, h2

I'm trying to make junit tests against transactions in my code using in-memory database H2. 
Everything looks fine - tables were created from hbm2ddl, inserts were performed but select is returning null.

Junit test fails on line :

```
  assertNotNull(artifactManager.getArtifact(id));
```

Whole test

```
@Test
@Transactional()
@Rollback(true)
public void failTransactionOnUpdateArtifactStateArtifactVerification() throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
    //GIVEN
    //some initialization already happened
    artifactManager.saveArtifact(artifact);

    //WHEN
    HibernateException exc = Mockito.mock(HibernateException.class);
    Mockito.when(historyDao.saveArtifactInHistory(artifact, ver)).thenThrow(exc);

    //THEN
    //artifact should be present in DB
    assertNotNull(artifactManager.getArtifact(id));
    assertEquals(artifactManager.getArtifact(id).getState().getType(),StateTypes.SENT);

    //and after exception rollback on artifacts Table should be performed and no artifacts should be present in DB
    try{
        stateService.updateArtifactState( ver,artifact);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //updateArtifact(artifact); should be rolled back and state reverted to SENT
    assertEquals(artifactManager.getArtifact(id).getState().getType(),StateTypes.SENT);
}
```

Relevant part of console log:

```
2013-01-11 15:02:21,538 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] - <schema update complete>
2013-01-11 15:02:21,934 INFO [org.acegisecurity.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor] - <Validated configuration attributes>    Hibernate: select artifact0_.Id as Id99_4_, artifact0_.CrosscheckerID as Crossche7_99_4_, artifact0_.CategoryID as CategoryID99_4_, artifact0_.CreationDate as Creation2_99_4_, artifact0_.Description as Descript3_99_4_, artifact0_.FileChecksum as FileChec4_99_4_, artifact0_.ReportID as ReportID99_4_, artifact0_.StateID as StateID99_4_, artifact0_.StateChangeDate as StateCha5_99_4_, artifact0_.Storage as Storage99_4_, user1_.ID as ID86_0_, user1_.Name as Name86_0_, user1_.Surname as Surname86_0_, user1_.username as username86_0_, user1_.jobPositionID as jobPosit5_86_0_, user1_.Email as Email86_0_, user1_.NSNID as NSNID86_0_, user1_.PESEL as PESEL86_0_, user1_.NIP as NIP86_0_, user1_.InProgram as InProgram86_0_, user1_.Employeed as Employeed86_0_, user1_.OutsidePoland as Outside12_86_0_, user1_.Password as Password86_0_, user1_.IncomeCosts as IncomeC14_86_0_, user1_.SupervisorID as Supervi15_86_0_, user1_.Disclosure as Disclosure86_0_, user1_.UserState as UserState86_0_, user1_.FailedLoginAttempts as FailedL18_86_0_, user1_.LastFailedLoginAttempt as LastFai19_86_0_, category2_.ID as ID107_1_, category2_.Name as Name107_1_, category2_."Order" as Order3_107_1_, report3_.ID as ID88_2_, report3_.UserID as UserID88_2_, report3_.StateID as StateID88_2_, report3_.CreationDate as Creation4_88_2_, report3_.StateChangeDate as StateCha5_88_2_, report3_.SupervisorID as Supervis6_88_2_, report3_.AccepterId as AccepterId88_2_, report3_.IncomeCosts as IncomeCo8_88_2_, report3_.AccInProg as AccInProg88_2_, state4_.ID as ID89_3_, state4_.Name as Name89_3_ from Artifacts artifact0_ left outer join Users user1_ on artifact0_.CrosscheckerID=user1_.ID left outer join Categories category2_ on artifact0_.CategoryID=category2_.ID left outer join Reports report3_ on artifact0_.ReportID=report3_.ID left outer join States state4_ on artifact0_.StateID=state4_.ID where artifact0_.Id=?
Hibernate: select max(ID) from Reports
Hibernate: select state0_.ID as ID89_0_, state0_.Name as Name89_0_ from States state0_ where state0_.ID=?
Hibernate: select max(ID) from States
Hibernate: insert into Reports (UserID, StateID, CreationDate, StateChangeDate, SupervisorID, AccepterId, IncomeCosts, AccInProg, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into States (Name, ID) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Artifacts (Id, CrosscheckerID, CategoryID, CreationDate, Description, FileChecksum, ReportID, StateID, StateChangeDate, Storage) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select artifact0_.Id as Id99_5_, artifact0_.CrosscheckerID as Crossche7_99_5_, artifact0_.CategoryID as CategoryID99_5_, artifact0_.CreationDate as Creation2_99_5_, artifact0_.Description as Descript3_99_5_, artifact0_.FileChecksum as FileChec4_99_5_, artifact0_.ReportID as ReportID99_5_, artifact0_.StateID as StateID99_5_, artifact0_.StateChangeDate as StateCha5_99_5_, artifact0_.Storage as Storage99_5_, user1_.ID as ID86_0_, user1_.Name as Name86_0_, user1_.Surname as Surname86_0_, user1_.username as username86_0_, user1_.jobPositionID as jobPosit5_86_0_, user1_.Email as Email86_0_, user1_.NSNID as NSNID86_0_, user1_.PESEL as PESEL86_0_, user1_.NIP as NIP86_0_, user1_.InProgram as InProgram86_0_, user1_.Employeed as Employeed86_0_, user1_.OutsidePoland as Outside12_86_0_, user1_.Password as Password86_0_, user1_.IncomeCosts as IncomeC14_86_0_, user1_.SupervisorID as Supervi15_86_0_, user1_.Disclosure as Disclosure86_0_, user1_.UserState as UserState86_0_, user1_.FailedLoginAttempts as FailedL18_86_0_, user1_.LastFailedLoginAttempt as LastFai19_86_0_, category2_.ID as ID107_1_, category2_.Name as Name107_1_, category2_."Order" as Order3_107_1_, report3_.ID as ID88_2_, report3_.UserID as UserID88_2_, report3_.StateID as StateID88_2_, report3_.CreationDate as Creation4_88_2_, report3_.StateChangeDate as StateCha5_88_2_, report3_.SupervisorID as Supervis6_88_2_, report3_.AccepterId as AccepterId88_2_, report3_.IncomeCosts as IncomeCo8_88_2_, report3_.AccInProg as AccInProg88_2_, user4_.ID as ID86_3_, user4_.Name as Name86_3_, user4_.Surname as Surname86_3_, user4_.username as username86_3_, user4_.jobPositionID as jobPosit5_86_3_, user4_.Email as Email86_3_, user4_.NSNID as NSNID86_3_, user4_.PESEL as PESEL86_3_, user4_.NIP as NIP86_3_, user4_.InProgram as InProgram86_3_, user4_.Employeed as Employeed86_3_, user4_.OutsidePoland as Outside12_86_3_, user4_.Password as Password86_3_, user4_.IncomeCosts as IncomeC14_86_3_, user4_.SupervisorID as Supervi15_86_3_, user4_.Disclosure as Disclosure86_3_, user4_.UserState as UserState86_3_, user4_.FailedLoginAttempts as FailedL18_86_3_, user4_.LastFailedLoginAttempt as LastFai19_86_3_, state5_.ID as ID89_4_, state5_.Name as Name89_4_ from Artifacts artifact0_ left outer join Users user1_ on artifact0_.CrosscheckerID=user1_.ID left outer join Categories category2_ on artifact0_.CategoryID=category2_.ID left outer join Reports report3_ on artifact0_.ReportID=report3_.ID left outer join Users user4_ on report3_.UserID=user4_.ID left outer join States state5_ on artifact0_.StateID=state5_.ID where artifact0_.Id=?
2013-01-11 15:02:22,213 INFO [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl] - <closing>
```

I've configured database as follows:

```
<bean id="dataSource" 
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:taxMemDB;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
<bean id="taxSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" >
    <property name="AnnotatedClasses">
        <list>    ...</list>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>mapping.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
            hibernate.connection.charSet=UTF-8
            hibernate.connection.pool_size=15
            hibernate.show_sql=true
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
        </value>
    </property>         
</bean>
<bean id="hibernateTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="taxSessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Any clue what may be wrong? Or should I attach more code ?

--Requested code
ArtifactManager:

```
 public Artifact getArtifact(long artifactId) {
    Artifact artifact = artifactDao.getArtifact(artifactId);
    return artifact;
}
```

ArtifactDao:

```
@Override
public Artifact getArtifact(Long id) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    return (Artifact) session.get(Artifact.class, id);
}
```

ArtifactManager.saveArifact:

```
 @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public boolean saveArtifact(Artifact artifact)throws IOException {

    String checksum = null;
    String userPath = null;

        checksum = checksumGenerator.generateChecksum(artifact.getFile().getInputStream());
        userPath = storageManager.upload(artifact);
        artifact.setStoragePath(userPath);
        artifact.setFileChecksum(checksum);
        if(artifact.getId()!=null){
            return  artifactDao.mergeArtifact(artifact);
        }else{
            return artifactDao.saveOrUpdateArtifact(artifact);
        }
}
```

ArifactDao part

```
@Override
public boolean saveOrUpdateArtifact(Artifact artifact) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    try {
        session.saveOrUpdate(artifact);
    } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean mergeArtifact(Artifact artifact) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    try {
        session.merge(artifact);
    } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: can you post the code for artifactManager.getArtifact(id)

Comment: Your insert statement in the log file shows a null value being inserted for a value.  What is the id being set to before you do a get on the artifact?  Is it a generated value.  Also your mock looks a little suspicious as well because they are not using matches on the when.

Comment: I've added requested code. The null in insert also bothers me but artifact is initialized with id(10L), even debugger shows is correctly but seems that hibernate doesn't see it..strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your method `ArtifactManager.getArtifact(id)` is looking directly into the database and since your transaction isn't commited yet... it find nothing.

Note that `@Rollback(true)` means that your transaction will never be commited.

**EDIT**

According your code, it seems that your looking to the current session to find the artifact (so it's OK event with non commited transaction).

Some other code that can be usefull to inspect:

- How do you specify the id on artifact in your mapping ? (auto-generated or manually defined ?)
- What's the code for your `saveArtifact` method ?

**EDIT**

I found a few annoying things with your code:

- Your are calling `saveArtifact` but you don't check the returning value. It's probably better to check before doing anything else. something like `assertTrue(artifactManager.saveArtifact(artifact)));`
- Usually, when merging an instance, it is interesting to get the merged instance back... but in your DAO you forget it and return a boolean instead. See [merge API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#merge%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29), the really interesting part is this

> The given instance (i.e. the parameter) **does not become associated with the session**.

- According your comments, the artifact is initialized with id=10L. So you will call the session.merge method. But your artifact is not supposed to be in the session, nor in the DB... so I think you should have some relevant error log somewhere ? no ?

Comment: Thanks, that might be the case, I will fill the table with different transaction and let you know if your hint worked.

Comment: In the presented case there were no errors, but I've followed your first advice and initialized db in separate transaction which helped, now problem is that hibernate doesn't perform rollback after expected exception(Could not roll back Hibernate Transaction; Transaction not started)